# Config multiple message properties

Tags: java, spring

I have properties files and I need to set them both to be loaded, but I have no idea how to do this with multiple properties

```
resources
`-- messages.properties
`-- handle.properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@PropertySources`. Annotate either a config class that holds the attributes of the files, or your `Main` class.

e.g.:

```
@PropertySources(
        {
        @PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:handle.properties")
        }
)
```